# Property replacement in IntelliJ IML file

Tags: intellij-idea

I recently migrated to IntelliJ 10. My .IML file has several properties such as $MODULE_DIR$ which set up the build environment. These are designed to be checked in so each user can configure his/her own local settings.

But everytime I checkin, IDEA replaces these *some of these* properties with the actual environment value, for example replacing every occurrence $MODULE_DIR$ in the iml file with my configured value "C:/Modules". This does not seem to happen for other properties, nor for other developers on the team using the same project. Am I missing some setting??

tia.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably read about [Path Variables](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/path-variables.html) in the Idea help.

I know that $MODULE_DIR$, $PROJECT_DIR$, ard $APPLICATION_HOME_DIR$ are used by Idea to determine where to find Module/Project/Idea stuff (jars etc). So I would guess not using these exact variable names will solve your problem.

Comment: Have you found a place which lists these built-in Path Variables?  I tried to navigate to the dialog mentioned in the documentation, but I can't find anything about `$MODULE_DIR$`, `$PROJECT_DIR$`, etc.  It only lists `$MAVEN_REPOSITORY$` on IntelliJ 13.1